# Updating dates with set delay

Tags: c#, mysql

In a windows form .net application working with MySQL, I have products that have multiple fabrication operations. Each operation has an expected start date and expected finish date. What I want to do is change the start date and end dates (push the dates) for the subsequent operations for that product when the user changes the dates on the first operation. So far, I've managed to change the dates of the following operations but they are all the same. If you could help me out with some code, it would be great. Should I be using a Datatable instead?Here is what I have so far:

```
 #region Push the predicted start date in planning table for same product id if end date is pushed forward
        DateTime oldStartDate = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime oldFinishDate = DateTime.Now;
        DateTime dt3 = DateTime.Parse(predicted_delivery.Text);
        DateTime dt4 = DateTime.Parse(new_predicted_delivery.Text);
        if(dt3.Date == dt4.Date)
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            int delay = (dt4 - dt3).Days;

            ConnectionStringSettings conSettings1 = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopmanagerConnectionString1"];
            MySqlConnection con1 = new MySqlConnection(conSettings1.ToString());
            MySqlCommand cmd1 = new MySqlCommand(@"select * from shopmanager.planning where part_id = @part_id;", con1);
            MySqlDataReader myReader1;

            try
            {
                con1.Open();
                cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@part_id", temp_part.item_id);
                myReader1 = cmd1.ExecuteReader();

                while (myReader1.Read())
                {
                    oldStartDate = myReader1.GetDateTime("predicted_start_date");
                    oldFinishDate = myReader1.GetDateTime("predicted_delivery");
                }
                cmd1.Parameters.Clear();

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
            }
            con1.Close();
            newStartDate = oldStartDate.AddDays(delay);
            newFinishDate = oldFinishDate.AddDays(delay);


            UpdateNewStartDate();
        }
        #endregion

    }
    #endregion

    #region Update new start and finish dates
    private void UpdateNewStartDate()
    {
        ConnectionStringSettings conSettings = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["shopmanagerConnectionString1"];
        MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(conSettings.ToString());
        MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand(@"update shopmanager.planning set predicted_start_date = @predicted_start_date, predicted_delivery = @predicted_delivery where part_id = @part_id", con);

        try
        {
            con.Open();
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@predicted_start_date", newStartDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@predicted_delivery", newFinishDate);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@part_id", temp_part.item_id);

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            cmd.Parameters.Clear();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        con.Close();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot going on in that code but I think the problem is that you're reading all the row, then only doing one calculation, and a single update.

If you do the calculation in C#, you'll need to do it for every row, like this:

```
           while (myReader1.Read())
            {
                oldStartDate = myReader1.GetDateTime("predicted_start_date");
                oldFinishDate = myReader1.GetDateTime("predicted_delivery");

                newStartDate = oldStartDate.AddDays(delay);
                newFinishDate = oldFinishDate.AddDays(delay);

                UpdateNewStartDate(partId, newStartDate, newFinishDate);
            }
            cmd1.Parameters.Clear();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        con1.Close();
```

Except 'UpdateNewStartDate();' updates all rows, so you'd need to add a parameter to specify which row you want to update.

A better way to do this might be to do it in the stored procedure, so you just specify the task and delay, and it updates the dates.

Also, as a general point, it helps to separate your database access code from your business logic, so you have smaller, easier to read functions. UpdateNewStartDate should really take all it's input from parameters, and not use variables that are shared with other functions - it's just confusing when you can't tell where something was set.

Comment: I used your above solution and it works now. The only thing I changed is partId to op-id. Everything is updating perfectly. Thanks.